# TypeError: A Future or coroutine is required with AWS lambda

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am setting up a lambda function which makes asynchronous requests using asyncio and aiohttp. Even thought the code works fine while running locally, once I upload it to lambda it returns:

```
"errorMessage": "A Future or coroutine is required"
```

I've looked at already opened issues such as [Boto3: A Future or coroutine is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54348725/boto3-a-future-or-coroutine-is-required) and [TypeError: A Future or coroutine is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450533/typeerror-a-future-or-coroutine-is-required) but couldn't make it to work.

I am not sure why is returning the error message while I have a defined coroutine

```
base_url = "https://www.reed.co.uk/api/1.0/jobs/"

url_list = [
"38012438",
"38012437",
"38012436"]

def lambda_handler(event, context):
client = boto3.client('s3',
                      aws_access_key_id="aws_access_key_id",
                      aws_secret_access_key="aws_secret_access_key")

async def fetch(session, url):
    auth = aiohttp.BasicAuth(login='login', password='')
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(auth=auth) as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.json()

async def fetch_all(urls, loop):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        results = await asyncio.gather(*[fetch(session, base_url + url) for url in url_list], return_exceptions=True)
        return results

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
htmls = loop.run_until_complete(fetch_all(urls, loop))
#I believe this is where the coroutine is 

with open("/tmp/JOBS.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(htmls, f)
```

I just want the combined content of my requests to be uploaded to a json file.

I apologise for my limited coding skills as I am new to python, lambda and etc.

Comment: Don’t use `@asyncio.coroutine` with an `async def`.

Comment: @dirn I've tried it without and it does not work.

Comment: I wasn’t proposing that as an answer. They are redundant and using them together could very well lead to unexpected behavior as they each cause syntax to change in different ways.

Answer (score 2):

Check your requirements.txt file. I got the same error when I added asyncio to the requirements.txt. It seems like AWS uses a special version of python. Asyncio is a part of python. And if you install it separately then it doesn't work in AWS Lambda.

Comment: But I haven't uploaded a requirements.txt as this is straight the code from the AWS console. I haven't uploaded it for the same reason that all the libraries used in my code are part of python, so I thought it won't be needed.

Comment: This fixed an issue we had on AWS Glue as well